# Use data from stored procedure for insert or update a table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I have a stored procedure for query some data. I want get this data and put into table or update the table with these data. how can i get this? I have tried many methods and all fail. somebody can help me please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the Stored Procedure using [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) if it doesn't use parameters, or if you can hardcode the parameters, e.g.

```
update othertable
  set ....
from openquery([SQLSERVER], 'exec ABC') X
join othertable ....
```

(Replace SQLSERVER with the name of the server/instance.)

Or you can put the data from the proc into a temp table then join to it, e.g.

```
insert #tmptablename
exec ABC 1,2,3
```

(where you first create #tmptablename with the exact columns expected from the resultset from proc "ABC")